# Segmentation fault with glCompressedTexImage2D

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I'm running an OpenGL ES application on a device that supports the `GL_OES_texture_compression_astc` extension. I have a 3000x2000 pixel texture, and when I call `glTexImage2D`, everything runs fine.

To compress the image, I downloaded the [ASTC encoder](https://github.com/ARM-software/astc-encoder) and executed the following command:

`./astcenc.exe -c player.png player.astc 6x5 -medium`

But when I use player.astc in `glCompressedTexImage2D`, the function causes a segmentation fault. Here's my code:

`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tids[0]);
glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_6x5_KHR, 3000, 2000, 0, size, data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);`

I've checked `size` and `data`, and they appear to be fine. Is there anything I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: You say value of ``size`` is fine, but if you get a segfault fault rather than rendering corruption, then that is likely to be the problem. So what value of size are you passing?

Comment: Based on my understanding of the algorithm, the compressed size should be (3000/6)*(2000/5)*16 = 3200000. The size of the compressed file is 3200016 bytes, which is close. I figured I could use the file size as the size of the compressed image, but I was mistaken. It must be set to exactly 3200000. That's a little frustrating, frankly.

Comment: Yep - the compressor adds a metadata header, so I think you need to knock that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of ASTC texture usage in the Mali OpenGL ES SDK:

http://malideveloper.arm.com/sample-code/astc-textures/